# Geolocation or geohash grid/bucket key value store possible with Elastic Search?

Tags: geolocation, elasticsearch, geohashing

Is it possible to use Elastic Search as a geohash key-value store?

For example, I'd like to store moving objects into Elastic Search, using their geohash as an index. Write speed isn't too important, just read speed. So I'd like to use a key-value geohash lookup, which would theoretically be fast.

I'm not sure how Elastic Search works under the covers, so would this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

As an update, I got this working, and it was much simpler than I thought. I indexed the location information using a geohash instead of longitude/latitude, and as a bonus was able to immediately have zoom out support because I could just drop the geohash' last character. Also the 'return neighbor' boolean flag in elasticsearch allowed me to take care of boundary edge cases.

This probably will return more information than is needed, but on the client side you can whittle it down to just the locations you need.